# WCF service reference in class library

Tags: wcf, endpoint

I added wcf service (exposed by biztalk) proxy and app.config file in VS 2005 class library project and i am calling this class library methods from windows application. In this case getting error while creating service instance, so i moved app.config file from class library to window applcation, now working fine.
Question: If i will change service url from machine001 to machine002 in config file (from bin folder but not from application) and run the app from exe file. Will it work without build.

Answer (score 0):

Class library configuration always depends on configuration file (web.config / app.config) of parent application that is really using it. And Parent application should be a console / winform / ASP.NET application and can be a windows service. Any change in WinForm's app.config will change the behavior of your class library.

To Answer your question, Yes if you change service url from machine001 to machine002 in config file of windows application it will work if machine002 is hosting the WCF service.

Hope it clears your doubt.